# Is there a black-box version of a postfix-dovecot mail server?

Tags: linux, email, smtp, postfix-mta

I have been going about setting up a a mail server using Dovecot and Postfix. As I am going along, I wondered if there is an out of the box equivalent ?

That is, is there a package for a command line function which can send and/or receive mail ?

I have been running an Apache web server for a few years and am comfortable with writing directives in apaches .conf files, so any explanations or tips in terms of this would be helpful. Being able to transmit GET/POST content using Apache, I would have expected there to be a similar method for sending email, though it doesn't seem to be the case so far.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 (focal) with the Bash shell.

Comment: Mail and Apache httpd have nothing to do with each other. Also note [help/on-topic], as this doesn't look programming related (or edit your question to be on topic)